# Can Apache APISIX support Layer 4 and Layer 7 proxies by default and which Layer 7 and Layer 4 protocols are supported respectively?

Tags: tcp, api-gateway, apache-apisix

I am recently learning Apache APISIX and I would like to ask about the proxy layer 7, and layer 4 protocol.
Can Apache APISIX proxy TCP and UDP directly, and what are the seven-layer protocols supported? What layer 4 protocols are supported?

Answer (score 0):

for TCP/UDP, you could use `stream-route` feature to support them.

> TCP is the protocol for many popular applications and services, such as > > > LDAP, MySQL, and RTMP. UDP (User Datagram Protocol) is the protocol for many > popular non-transactional applications, such as DNS, syslog, and RADIUS.
> APISIX can dynamically load balancing TCP/UDP proxy. In Nginx world, we call > TCP/UDP proxy to stream proxy, we followed this statement.

Please check https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/stream-proxy